# Where are my custom tabs?

Tags: support

For a past couple of days, I am not able to see my custom tabs. I see only default tabs e.g. interesting, featured, hot etc. and no option to add tabs is available.

Are tabs have been removed from site? if not how do I get my tabs back.

[image: no tabs image]